# Можно ли отобразить значки элементам меню со свойством showAsAction="never"

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-menu

Здравствуйте! Можно ли отобразить значки элементам меню со свойством showAsAction="never"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке слева свойство у значком showAsAction="always", так и должно быть.

Хотелось бы, чтобы на правой картинке, отображались значки элементов меню слева от текста, это возможно?

**UPDATE:**

Нашел способ, как по мне, достаточно хороший, без оверрайда методов в активити, нужно только подправить немного XML-файл. Меню более гибким получается, можно сделать свой значок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем нужно сделать такую конструкцию, когда один из элементов меню сам является меню:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_show_ir_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_friendslist"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="List"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar

Только не нужно хардкодить в тайтле
`android:title="List"` - это всего лишь пример. Лучше вынести в стринг и прописать `android:title="@string/name"`

Ну и `android:showAsAction="always"`, скорее всего нужно будет прописать `app:showAsAction="always"`, где app - это `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337653/3212712). Добавьте этот метод в вашу активити:

```
/**
 * workaround from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337653/3212712 to show menu icons
 */
@Override
protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu)
{
    if (menu != null)
    {
        if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder"))
        {
            try
            {
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onMenuOpened...unable to set icons for overflow menu", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
}
```

Раньше иконки отображались, но потом гугл решил, что это ему не нравится и приходится использовать вот такой костыль.